# How to insert data directly into WordPress database from iPhone app using JSON-API?

Tags: ios, wordpress, json-api, wordpress-json-api

I am developing IOS app where users will be login into my WordPress site and complete the form and send the data to WordPress Database. Here I am using JSON API for Wordpress to validate users. Is there any plugin which allow me to enter data to WP database directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON API to add a post to Wordpress. You do have to implement Oauth2 if you want to do so. You could use one of these libraries for that: https://cocoapods.org/?q=oauth

See the API documentation for information about posting something: https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/